# Преследование персонажа по оси Х

Tags: c#, unity3d

В платформере пила преследует персонажа, все хорошо, но получается, что когда персонаж прыгает, то пила следует за ним. Как сделать движение пилы только по оси Х?

```
void Start()
{
    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Если `position` это координаты в дпск, то занулить координату Y

Comment: Что такое дпск? И то, что занулить, я то сам понял, но с точки зрения кода это как сделать?

Comment: Упрощённо, координаты `(x; y)`. Почитайте документацию, что такое `position` и как его изменять

Comment: Спасибо, кэп. Мог и не тратить свое время

Comment: @MaximKapko Другими словами он хотел сказать `меняйте только x` :-)

Comment: @MaximKapko `transform.position.x = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime).x;`

Comment: @MaximKapko Если код сверху выдаёт ошибку попробуйте вот так: `transform.position = new Vector2(Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime).x, 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите изменять движение только по оси X, то вам не нужно изменять его положение по оси Y. То есть вот эту строчку:

`transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);`

нужно заменить на что-то подобное:

`transform.position = new Vector2(Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime).x, [пила].transform.position.y);`

То есть сначала с помощью функции вы сдвигаете пилу к персонажу (причем и по х и по y), потом с помощью `.x` берете смещение только по х, после чего в качестве координаты y подставляете координату сомой пилы по y, то есть то же, что и было до сдвига.

Другой вариант - это заменять y на на необходимый (то есть на y самой пилы) прямо в функции MoveTowards, тогда эта строка будет выглядеть так:

`transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector2(target.position.x, [пила].transform.position.y), speed * Time.deltaTime);`

Третий вариант - это сделать переменную `targetPosition`, которая будет равна:

`targetPosition = new Vector2(target.position.x, [пила].transform.position.y)`

Остается только заменить точку назначения (второй параметр) в функции MoveTowards на переменную targetPosition.

Надеюсь помог! Если есть вопросы, задавайте!

Comment: Просто огромное человеческое спасибо! Сделал по 2 способу и сразу с 1 раза всё получилось!

Comment: @Maxim, если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста, если не трудно, нажмите на стрелочку вверх (типа лайка) и на галочку (это значит, что вы приняли ответ и вопрос решен). Так другие люди поймут, что вопрос уже решен, а я получу репутацию за ответ:)